# How can we add special options to leaflet popup?

Tags: angular, leaflet, popup

I want to add an option that inherit from DivOverlay :
https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup

[image]

The bindpopup doesn't recognise the option:
[image]

anyone know how to add the special options ?

I need this option to add buttons and listeners in the popup

Comment: It's not the same question.

Comment: I still need the options for other things so if you can just answer my question it will be nice